# Printer shaking - Marlin 2.0

Tags: marlin, stepper-driver

I just replaced the board on my Creality CR-10 with a 32-bit SKR Mini E3 V2.0 control board that runs Marlin 2.0.  With the new control board, the printer's Y-Axis moves vibrate so much that it blurs the camera I am using that is connected to the bed.

I have checked the mechanical stuff and it seems like the issue is the stepper motors are running choppily instead of smoothly.

I know that 32-bit Marlin has lots of things I can tweak.  Are there settings I should be checking?  Where do I start?

Comment: Are you sure you're just not using different acceleration/jerk limits than with the original board's firmware build?

Comment: I'm using the Marlin defaults for both.  However, the choppiness happens even during long straight moves (like homing) so I don't think it is a jerk/acceleration issue.

Comment: Do you have video/audio showing the issue? I'm not sure I understand what "choppiness" means here.

Comment: I mean that the Steppers aren't rotating at a steady speed.  It seems as they are stepping, stopping, stepping, stopping creating a very choppy movement of the axis.  You can feel the studdering by hand and it is painfully obvious through the picam..  (With the steppers off, the mechanism is perfectly smooth)

Comment: Did you do anything odd with the microstepping configuration?

Comment: Nothing that wasn't in the provided config for the SKR Mini E3 V2.  What should they be set to, and how can I check?  The Configuration_adv.h shows it is set to 16 microsteps, but I'd like to be able to config that it actually is working that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be mechanical.  The arm that I mounted the camera on had developed a crack where it connects to the build platform.  I used some superglue to repair the crack and the camera shaking went away.

The lesson here is to check EVERYTHING mechanical before trying to blame shaking on the firmware.